# RDLC source code How to i change text color in table column

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

How do i set the color of text in RDLC? Many example show changing color using Microsoft visual basic. But how do i add it in my code without it. I see many examples giving the same code such as below

My Condition (value): Textbox4 = 0

```
=IIF(Fields!Textbox4.Value = 0,"Red","Black").
```

But where do i put them? I tried to put in between the styles but it doesnt work.

```
<TablixCell>
    <CellContents>
        <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
            <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
            <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                            <Value>Total Work Time</Value>
                            <Style>
                                <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                        </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style>
                        <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                    </Style>
                </Paragraph>
            </Paragraphs>
            <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
            <Style>
                <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
            </Style>
        </Textbox>
    </CellContents>
</TablixCell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `tablecell` where you want conditional color. Then go to `Placeholder Properties..` then select `Font` then you can see beside `color dropdown` there is a `button` named `Fx`. Click the button and put your code there

```
=IIF(Fields!Textbox4.Value = 0,"Red","Black")
```

You are correct about putting it in the `style` tag. But there is some issue.I think you post the code for header `textbox`. You should do it in the value `textbox`. Value `textbox` will contain a `DbColumn` from your `dataset` as value and that field should look like below..

```
<TablixCell>
<CellContents>
    <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
                <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                        <Value>=Fields!SomeDbColumn.Value</Value>
                        <Style>
                            <Color>=IIF(Fields!SomeDbColumn.Value = 0,"Red","Black")</Color>
                            <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                            <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                        </Style>
                    </TextRun>
                </TextRuns>
                <Style>
                    <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                </Style>
            </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>SomeDbColumn</rd:DefaultName>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                <Style>Solid</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
    </Textbox>
</CellContents>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but this one is by using Microsoft Visual Studio. How do i do it manually using the code given above. I know i have to put it in <Style> tag but at which line should i use the <Color> tag. I tried to put inside styles but it produces error

Comment: FYI, I dont have microsoft visual studio installed now